# How do I write this AND/OR statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

I have 2 fields: `qty_released` and `qty_complete`. I need to exclude rows where the `qty_released = 1` and `qty_complete = 0` ***at the same time.*** I can't do this:

```
--rest of code

and j.qty_released != 1
and j.qty_complete != 0

--rest of code
```

...because there might be valid times when `j.qty_complete = 0` while `j.qty_released > 1`. Similar situation for `j.qty_released = 1`. How should I write this? I need the query to consider both of these at the same time when filtering through a particular row.

Comment: can `qty_released` or `qty_complete` be `null`?

Comment: @SqlZim nope. Never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
where not (qty_released = 1 and qty_complete = 0)
```

Or logical equivalent, but harder to read IMHO:

```
where (qty_released != 1 or qty_complete != 0)
```

Comment: That works, but I'm curious - this kinda just seems like the negation of `and (j.qty_released != 1 and j.qty_complete != 0)`, which **doesn't** work. Why is this?

Comment: @DarthVoid this is a 'not and' (`NAND`) operation, vs your 'not' and 'not' operation

Comment: @SqlZim I don't really see the difference though. Could you explain the difference between NAND and "not and not"?

Comment: @DarthVoid Check out [logic gate - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate), it has sample input and output for all binary scenarios and their associated logic gates (and,or,nand,nor,xor,xnor)

Comment: @SqlZim since there are only 2 ways of coding it, same answer is likely

Comment: @Bohemian True, I just thought your answer was better before it repeated the other answer.

Comment: @SqlZim oh, I was answering David's comment/question of why his code didn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE/AND (j.qty_released <> 1 OR j.qty_complete > 0)
```

In English: Include rows where `qty_released` is not `1` *OR*, if it is 1, then `qty_complete` must be greater than 0. So rows filtered out will be rows that meet the condition `qty_released = 1 AND qty_complete = 0`.

Comment: This also works, but now I'm debating if there is a difference between the 2 current answers. Both answers return the same results. Any advice on which to use?

Comment: @DarthVoid - I would pick the Sql statement that you are most comfortable with. From a technical standpoint they are equivalent.